# Ethereum remix vs code extension not working

Tags: solidity, remix, ether, ethers.js, visual-studio-code

[image: blank remix extension]I installed ethereum remix extension on vs code today. It isn't working. When I click on remix logo on left side, two sections - Remix and Remix Plugins starts loading and after a minute, loading stops and all blank. How to solve this issue.

Comment: Hey, can you please provide an error of it? You can activate the console by going to Help > Toggle Developer Tools and clicking "Console". Let me know